# What actually happens internally in a invalid memory access?

Tags: memory, runtime, theory

I wonder what really happens, internally, when you try to access to an illegal memory address.

I mean, I know you'll get a segmentation fault, but what really happens in the device (microchip or CPU)?

For example:

```
int *p = NULL;
*p = 0;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: At the 'bottom', see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault - these are then handled (fsvo) and propagated up through the operating system